# MySQL group_concat() ordering by case statement values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, group-concat

In a MySQL `group_concat()` clause, I'm trying to order the resulting values of a case statement. The following query configuration properly orders `things.name` but does not order the 'Non-US' or 'Unknown' values within the same context.

```
SELECT 
  things.id
  ,group_concat(DISTINCT 
    CASE
    WHEN things.name <> 'United States' THEN 'Non-US'
    WHEN things.name IS NULL THEN 'Unknown'
    ELSE things.name
    END
  ORDER BY name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM things
GROUP BY things.id
```

I want to do something like this, but it's not working:

```
SELECT 
  things.id
  ,group_concat(DISTINCT 
    (CASE
    WHEN things.name <> 'United States' THEN 'Non-US'
    WHEN things.name IS NULL THEN 'Unknown'
    ELSE things.name
    END) AS new_name
  ORDER BY new_name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM things
GROUP BY things.id
```

Is there a way to sort by "new_name" without using sub-queries/ nested queries?

Comment: If it won't accept the alias `new_name` in the `ORDER BY`, it still should accept the entire `CASE` expression as `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE...END ORDER BY CASE WHEN things.name....END SEPARATOR ', ')`  It would be ugly, but worth a try. Otherwise you would probably need a subquery to stuff the sort value into a real column.

Comment: A subquery would be much cleaner than my answer below; though grouping on the id field implies you shouldn't really need the GROUP_CONCAT() at all.

Comment: the id field in this example was just thrown in there for illustration purposes (perhaps not the best choice). the real query is different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can accomplish this by ordering by *column position* instead of *column name*.

For your case `ORDER BY 1` should work.

```
SELECT 
  things.id
  ,group_concat(DISTINCT 
    CASE
    WHEN things.name <> 'United States' THEN 'Non-US'
    WHEN things.name IS NULL THEN 'Unknown'
    ELSE things.name
    END
  ORDER BY 1 SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM things
GROUP BY things.id
```

Comment: Ah, I'd *hoped* that was what that unsigned_integer bit in the manual's syntax definition actually referred to.  But the manual doesn't explain it!  It's not actually a *column* position, BTW, since it's not part of a SELECT or a table; it's just the position of the expression in the GROUP_CONCAT argument list, if that is indeed how it works.

Answer (score 0):

A session variable might work, but I am not sure the order of evaluation within a GROUP_CONCAT():

```
SELECT 
  things.id
  , group_concat(DISTINCT 
      @new_name := (CASE
        WHEN things.name <> 'United States' THEN 'Non-US'
        WHEN things.name IS NULL THEN 'Unknown'
        ELSE things.name
        END
      ) ORDER BY @new_name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM things
GROUP BY things.id
;
```

If that doesn't work, you could try doing the assignment in the ORDER BY section instead, and just using @new_name in the pre-ORDER BY.