# mysql query with grouping and concatenate rows into one row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, concatenation

I have the table in mysql with records:

[image]

I've written the sql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number_of_contacts, channel_id, direction
FROM cic_case_contacts
WHERE case_id = 328678
GROUP BY channel_id, direction
```

and the result looks like:

[image]

I would like to obtain something like below(based on above data):

[image]

I was trying to obtaining that with sql query by using my_sql_function **GROUP_CONCAT** but it dosen't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number_of_contacts, channel_id, GROUP_CONCAT(direction SEPARATOR ', ') AS directions
FROM cic_case_contacts
WHERE case_id = 328678 AND id IN(149196, 149195, 149194, 149193, 149192) AND `office_id` = 10
GROUP BY channel_id
ORDER BY channel_id
```

I would be greateful for help.

Comment: Use `case` statement inside the `Group_concat`

Comment: Something like this -> [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303401/2845389)

Comment: But how should I calc number of_contacts per group_concat function and CASE and WHEN words?

Comment: updated the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fzSEf2xJsmtSt8h2bC1Ec9/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` on a sub query as follows:

```
SELECT channelid, GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(direction, ': ', c)
    ORDER BY direction
    SEPARATOR ', '
) AS summary
FROM (
    SELECT channelid, direction, COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM t
    GROUP BY channelid, direction
) x
GROUP BY channelid
```

Or simply use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT channelid, CONCAT_WS(', ',
    CONCAT('in: ',  COUNT(CASE WHEN direction = 'in'  THEN 1 END)),
    CONCAT('out: ', COUNT(CASE WHEN direction = 'out' THEN 1 END))
) AS summary
FROM t
GROUP BY channelid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Concat` in `MySQL`

```
drop table if exists Demo;
CREATE TABLE Demo 
(
  ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  channelid int,
  Name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO Demo(channelid, Name)VALUES
(1,'in'),(1,'out'),(1,'in'),(1,'out'),(2,'in'),(2,'out'),(1,'in'),(1,'out'),(1,'in'),(2,'out'),(2,'in'),(2,'out'),(2,'in'),(1,'in'),(1,'in');
```

Query

```
SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
        channelid, 
        group_concat ( concat(name,':',channelid) ) 
FROM Demo
group by channelid;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

See the results the the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fzSEf2xJsmtSt8h2bC1Ec9/0)

Answer (score 0):

Please find below working code as per your requirement :

```
select tb.channelid, group_concat
(
  concat(tb.name,':',tb.MyCol2Count)

) as v1
from
(Select tbl.channelid,tbl.name,(LENGTH(tbl.val) - LENGTH(REPLACE(tbl.val,",","")) + 1) AS MyCol2Count
from 
(SELECT channelid, group_concat
(
  concat(name,':',channelid)

) as val,name
FROM Demo
group by channelid,Name) as tbl) as tb group by tb.channelid
```

You can check on below screenshot : http://springinfosoft.com/code/Groupby_code.png